# How do I call an 8-digit Singapore number from the US?

Tags: usa, singapore, communication

I have an 8-digit Singapore cell phone number that I’d like to call.  But I’m in the US, so my question is, what international calling code do I need to put before the 8 digits?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Generally, you dial (international access code) + (country code) + (8 digit number).

The country code for Singapore is 65 (easy to google). [The international access code from the US is 011.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes)  From a cell phone the + key can replace the international access code.

Comment: To place the call with operator assistance (does that even exist anymore?), you would dial 01 instead of 011.

Answer (score 14):

Generally when calling internationally there are three parts to the number you dial.

1. The international dialiing prefix for the country you are calling from. In North america this is "011" (in much of the rest of the world it is 00). When calling from a mobile phone you can use the special symbol "+" instead of the international dialing prefix, this is useful when your phone may be used in more than one country.
2. The country code for the country you are calling. Singapore is 65.
3. The national number within the destination country. In the case of singapore this is 8 digits long. In some countries it is customary to write phone numbers including a national calling prefix which needs to be removed when putting the number into international form, but that doesn't appear to be an issue with singapore as they have no area codes in their phone system.

So your complete number from the US would be 011 65 XXXXXXXX

Comment: You have to wonder if, these days, it's even worth mentioning the "011".  (For example, come to think on it, incredibly, I *did not know* it's 011 in the US, everyone has just used "plus sign" for years now.)

Comment: Well I didn't even know that it was a code for the country you are calling from. I used to use "00" or "+" and thought it was the same for everyone (I'm using "+" more now but it's still in my mind "*either 00 or +*")

Comment: @Fattie land line telephones still exist, and the OP does not specify whether the call is being placed with one.  With such a phone, there is no plus sign.  Peter Green, to place the call with operator assistance, substitute 01 for 011.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning (assuming this is still relevant) that you used to have to wait for the tones between those steps or it wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't think stuff like that has been relevant for a long time, AIUI on any vaugely modern phone system either the phone itself (for cellular and VOIP) or the local exchange (for landlines) reads in the whole number, and it's processed as digital data from there on out.

Answer (score 3):

> {International prefix} + {country code} + {number}

For Singapore, the country code is `65`

```
From a mobile device: +65 #### ####
From a land line: 011 65 #### ####
```

Side note: Since the country code for Canada/USA is `1` you could dial those 9-digit numbers the exact same way:

```
From a mobile device: +1 (212) 555-5555
From a land line: 011 1 (212) 555-5555
```

Comment: For operator assistance, such as to place the call collect, use `01 65 #### ####`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a travel forum, I would suggest downloading Skype (free) first and adding a bit of money to it (increments of around US$10) and calling through Skype out.

You just pick the country(Singapore in this case) from the drop-down list and it adds the country code and access code prefix (+65 in this case) for you. It (as of the time of this writing) costs USD $0.023/minute plus a $0.049 connection fee, so you can talk your head off for cheap. If the person on the other end uses a computer, you can talk for free, and no need to add money.

It's useful for calling people on phones just about anywhere from just about anywhere, and you can use Wifi or cellular service provided it's fast enough (VPN sometimes required).

It also allows you to call toll-free numbers that are usually not accessible at all from outside some defined calling area.

The 011 prefix you would use in the US and Canada to call overseas **from a land line** is not necessarily going to be the same if  you're calling from another country, but fortunately cell phone networks have simplified things by just using the "+".